# simple front controller causes css and javascript broken in php

Tags: javascript, php, css, url-routing

I'm trying to implement a simple front controller in php..
In my index.php;

```
 $parts = array_slice(explode('/',$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]),3);

 if(file_exists($parts[0].'.php'))
    include $parts[0].'.php';
 else
    echo 'not found';
```

so i typed the adress bar localhost/myroot/index.php/home, I expect to include home.php.
It's include home.php but without external css files and javascript sources.. None of them are loaded..

in home.php,

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/master.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/master.js"></script>
```

root directory has styles and scripts directories
/myroot/styles/master.css
/myroot/scripts/master.js

so if i type localhost/myroot/home.php, it works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on teresko's answer...

The browser doesn't know (or care) what form your URLs are in.  When you use a relative path for your CSS and JavaScript, it expects them to be relative to the last directory.

So, if your page is at `/somecontroller/somepage/someparamater`, and you reference `/scripts/master.js`, then the browser is going to request `/somecontroller/somepage/someparameter/scripts/master.js`.

The solution is to simply put a `/` in front of those paths so that they are relative to the site root.

Answer (score 1):

Stop using relative URLs for your CSS and JS